# Show google map on screen capture

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, screenshot, screen-capture

Good day guys, i programmatically screen capture on eclipse, it was successful but the google map fragment only shows black page on my screen capture result. What should i do to show the map on my screen captures?

here is my code:

```
public void download (View v){
View view = findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
//ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
FrameLayout iv = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map);
//iv.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
                //we check if external storage is available, otherwise display an error message to the user
               File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
               File directory = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Transit_Guide_Downloads");
               directory.mkdirs();
               String filename = "download_" + i + ".jpg";
               File yourFile = new File(directory, filename);
               while (yourFile.exists()) {
                    i++;
                    filename = "download_" + i + ".jpg";
                    yourFile = new File(directory, filename);
               }
               if (!yourFile.exists()){
                    if (directory.canWrite())
                    {
                       try {
                             FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(yourFile, true);
                             bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                             out.flush();
                             out.close();
                             Toast.makeText(SecondMap.this, "File exported to /sdcard/Transit_Guide_Downloads/screenshot" + i + ".jpg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                             i++;
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }}
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(SecondMap.this, "SD Card not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
             }
```

Comment: Where your get the screen captures, is on the emulator or on a real device? Because I checked on my device, it works fine.

Comment: on my physical device, the program works but the map fragment is just black there's no map showing.

Answer (score 2):

If you can not show the `Google Map` on your device, most probably is that you did not get your Google Map v2 `API KEY` on the google `developer console`and put in your `Androidmanifest.xml`.

For how to get and show the map step by step, you can refer to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) and [here](http://javapapers.com/android/show-map-in-android/).